# how to show the line breaks of a nvarchar string from the database in an html page using repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Here's the deal.There's some `nvarchar` text in my database that have `CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)` for line breaks.I am using an `<asp:repeater>` to show and style the database's content.Here is how my aspx page looks like:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="dataTiltle">
                <%#Eval("datatitle") %> <br />
            </div>
            <div class="dataMain">
                <%#Eval("datamain") %>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SeparatorTemplate>
            <hr />
        </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and here's how I get the information from the database:

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table", conn);
conn.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
myRepeater.DataSource = reader;
myRepeater.DataBind();
reader.Close();
```

the `nvarchar`s I am talking about are in the `datamain` section.Now my problem is that I can't find a way to show the line breaks of the texts.The texts are being shown in a straight line until they reach the end of the `div`.But I want the text's own line breaks appear as well.What should I do?

Comment: how do you store the line breaks in DB ?? i mean <br/> or \n ?

Comment: as I said,I am doing the line breaks with `CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)` in db.But if your answer insists that I should use something else,it's ok!

Comment: you can call function that take 'datamain' and then parse it as you want instead of showing it directly

Comment: I am getting all the data using a `SqlDataAdapter`.So I have no control on the individual data.I have all of them together.Then I am using a repeater to show the individual.How can I change the data before binding it to the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can write a function in code behind that 'll do your logic. Inside it you simply replace the the characters `CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)` you get from database with `<br/>`

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="dataTiltle">
            <%#Eval("datatitle") %> <br />
        </div>
        <div class="dataMain">
            <%#Your_Function_Name(Eval("datamain")) %>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        <hr />
    </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

then from code behind write your public function:

```
public string Your_Function_Name(string datamain)
{
//now u have the value from DB in datamain. Do your required logic here then return the required value
}
```

Comment: Thanks,it worked.the `datamain` wasn't a string.I called it as an object in my function,and then converted it to a string.But The general idea was great!!thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the carriage return / line feed sequences when rendering the string read from the database with the HTML "<br/>".

Say you did this in a function called FormatAsHtml()... You could call that from within your repeater as above.

You could use string.Replace(@"\n\r", "<br/>") for the replacement.

Comment: I can't figure out how I can change the data when it is bound to the repeater.can you show me that?

Answer (score 0):

use the replace method of string to replace all the occurances of Char(10) and Char(13) and then assign it to your repeater control.
And if you want to edit the data without using the method above then you should fetch the data after formatting from database.

Comment: look at how I am getting the data from the DB.I don't have control over them one by one.And If there is a way,I don't now it.could you tell me?